# Hide a Category in Layered Navigation but Leave Active?

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, layered-navigation

I'm trying to hide select categories by ID in layered navigation only. I edited the code below by making the following line change `<?php if($this->useLayeredCategory($_category->getId() !=22,239,298,2983)): ?>` but it breaks layered navigation? What I'm I doing wrong?

**Path to File (left.phtml)**
- mystore\app\design\frontend\my-package\my-theme\template\layerednavcategory\catalog\navigation

```
<?php if (!$_current = $this->getCurrentCategory()) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php $_currentDD = false; ?>
<?php $_currentSub = false; ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block-layered-nav-categories">
    <div class="block-title">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="open">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php if($this->useLayeredCategory($_category->getId())): ?>
                    <?php $_currentDD = false; ?>
                    <?php if ($_category->getId() == $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()): ?>
                        <?php $_currentDD = true; ?>
                        <dt class="full current">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                            <span class="toggle current"></span>
                        </dt>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <dt class="full">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                            <span class="toggle"></span>
                        </dt>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <!--If top category contains current displayed category, show all subcategories in list -->
                    <dd <?php if($_currentDD){ echo "class=\"current\"";} ?>>
                        <ol>
                            <?php $_subcats = $this->getChildren($_category->getId())?>
                            <?php foreach ($_subcats as $_subcat): ?>
                                <?php $_currentSub = false; ?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php if(!$_current->getChildrenCount() > 0){
                                        $_current = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_current->getParentId());
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php $_subsubcats = $this->getChildren($_subcat->getId())?>
                                    <!-- Return all sub-subcategories -->
                                    <?php if (count($_subsubcats) > 0) :?>
                                        <!--if current category is not the sub_most_category get all subcategories-->
                                        <?php if($_subcat->getId() == $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()):?>
                                            <?php $_currentSub = true; ?>
                                            <div class="current">
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_subcat) ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_subcat->getName()) ?>
                                                </a>
                                                <span class="toggle current"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_subcat) ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_subcat->getName()) ?>
                                                </a>
                                                <span class="toggle"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif?>
                                        <ol <?php if($_currentSub){ echo "class=\"current current-sub\"";} ?> id="main-sub">
                                            <?php foreach ($_subsubcats as $_ssscat): ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <?php if (!($_ssscat->getId() == $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId())): ?>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_ssscat) ?>">
                                                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_ssscat->getName()) ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <span class="current current-sub">
                                                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_ssscat->getName()) ?>
                                                        </span>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </li>
                                            <?php endforeach ?>
                                        </ol>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_subcat) ?>">
                                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_subcat->getName()) ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach?>
                        </ol>
                    </dd>
            <?php else: ?>
                <dt>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                    </a>
                </dt>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which page specifically do you want to disable category filters from the layered nav

Comment: I want to disable select categories by ID. Like this (<?php if ($_category->getId() != 22): ?>) but I can't figure out how to correctly implement it into the code above.

Comment: You should place the filename (incl. the path relative to your project root) on top of the code-example so it's more clear about which file you're talking. Additionally you should highlight in your question what you did so far in the code-example and if/or-not/why(as you assume) it does (not) work for you. Otherwise your question tends to "ask for code" only which is bad style.